# Find Starting index of the decreasing sequence

Tags: matlab, find, sequence

I have a sequence extracted from the measurement file and the sequence is shown below.

> a=[2 1 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 3 4 5 4];

I want to find the starting indices of each decreasing sequence....
for eg: In the above sequence you can find the sequence starts decreasing at the following indices

```
 1.  [3 2 1] this sequence starts decreasing from the index 3,
 2.  [5 4 3 2] this sequence starts decreasing from the index 11,
 3.  [5 4] this sequence starts decreasing from the index 17.
```

Any idea regarding how to find this sequence starting point will be more useful... Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tried using functions namely
diff and findpattern(a, [4 3])....
when i use the findpattern function i have to mention all the pattern combinations in a list and check it... it is not a feasible function. I want to know if there is any other easier method of finding the sequence pattern in Matlab

Comment: Post your code please...

Comment: What would you like to have as result for `[3 3 2 1]` and `[3 2 2 2 1]`?

Comment: For the first array I would like to have a result as 1 since the decreasing point starts from second.... For the second array I would expect following result answer: 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
find(diff([0, diff(a) < 0]) == 1)
```

In other words find the index locations where the difference is negative (`diff(a) < 0`) and then choose only those that came after an increasing number.

Comment: in your previous program, i am unable to understand the last line 
    a=[2 1 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 3 4 5 4]
    diff(a)
    I=find(diff(a) < 0 )
    I2 = diff(I)
    I([true, I2~=1])
can you please shed your knowledge on this line I([true, I2~=1])
.... thks....

Comment: @BuBuBulji First off rather use the new version. ` I([true, I2~=1])`: so the `I2~=1` returns a logical matrix showing where elements are not 1, but it is one element shorter than `I` (because diff shortens by one element) and I know I always want to include the first element so I append a `true` to the beginning.

Comment: instead of 'true' you can also append the number '0' to it right?

Comment: @BuBuBulji give it a try. I think you'll find that you can't as it will cast to double and try access element 0 which is out of bounds. But give it go and see for yourself what happens